# TextView not effected onProgressChanged of seekBar

Tags: android

I have this extension of SeekBar:

```
package com.simplemathgame;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SeekBarPlus extends SeekBar implements OnSeekBarChangeListener{
    private TextView numberOfDrills;

    public SeekBarPlus(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SeekBarPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SeekBarPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }


    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
            boolean fromUser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w("SeekBarChanged", "change to" + progress);
        numberOfDrills.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
    }

    public void setTextView(TextView textView){
        numberOfDrills = textView;
        Log.w("SeekBar", "text to bar");
    }

}
```

And here is the main activity code:

```
package com.simplemathgame;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.simplemathgame.SeekBarPlus;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SeekBarPlus addSeekBar = (SeekBarPlus) findViewById(R.id.add_seek_bar);
        SeekBarPlus subSeekBar = (SeekBarPlus) findViewById(R.id.sub_seek_bar);
        SeekBarPlus mulSeekBar = (SeekBarPlus) findViewById(R.id.mul_seek_bar);
        SeekBarPlus divSeekBar = (SeekBarPlus) findViewById(R.id.div_seek_bar);

        TextView numberOfAddDrills = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.add_drills_number);
        TextView numberOfSubDrills = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sub_drills_number);
        TextView numberOfMulDrills = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mul_drills_number);
        TextView numberOfDivDrills = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.div_drills_number);

        addSeekBar.setTextView(numberOfAddDrills);
    subSeekBar.setTextView(numberOfSubDrills);
    mulSeekBar.setTextView(numberOfMulDrills);
    divSeekBar.setTextView(numberOfDivDrills);
    }   
}
```

### After I move the progress bar nothing happens, I have all the needed elements (TextViews).

### I would like:

I would like the SeekBarPlus Automatically listen to it's changes and react as I have coded in the onProgressChanged method,in other words I would like that onProgressChanged would be triggered without any code in the main activity.

### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: is `onProgressChanged` called? Are you sure you've overriden it properly? Add `@Override` to ensure its overriding something correctly. (add above of `public void onProgressChanged(`)

Comment: adding @Override gives an error "Description Resource Path Location Type
The method onProgressChanged(SeekBar, int, boolean) of type SeekBarPlus must override or implement a supertype method SeekBarPlus.java /SimpleMathGame/src/com/simplemathgame line 35 Java Problem
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the documentation:

> Clients of the SeekBar can attach a SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener to
>   be notified of the user's actions.

You need to have a listener on your Seekbar in order to update.

### Update

This is possible, but you have to create a single view to house everything and then attach it it that way. Once you have created this, then add the custom view to your layout file. Then add callbacks as necessary from your custom view. Of course this implies that you added your listeners **IN** your custom view class.

### Example

You would have something like this in your class, make **sure to set the orientation of the** views:

```
 package com.blah.my.package
    class MyCustomClass extends LinearLayout{

    CustomSeekbar v1 ...

    CustomSeekbar v2 ...

    CustomSeekbar v3 ...

    CustomSeekbar v4 ...

    CustomSeekbar v5 ...

    CustomSeekbar v6 ...

    ...

    Constructors and methods n' stuff...


    }
```

Once you have this, then in your layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.blah.my.package.MyCustomClass ... />
    ...
<LinearLayout>
```

To learn more:
http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: The questions is: Is it possible to do this in the SeekBarPlus class and not in the main activity code.

Comment: Do what? Please be more clear. What would you like to do in the SeekBarPlus class  that you are doing in your main activity code?

Comment: In this case, you'd have to programatically create the TextViews in your Seekbar, by encasing them in a Single View that contains both.

Comment: I will try to explain my self better. I don't want to add in my MainActivity the OnSeekBarChangeListener. I want for each member of class SeekBarPlus to "listen" to any changes in it's progress.

Comment: Please update your question with as much clarity as you can. Be specific.

Comment: can you please provide some example, the SeekBarPlus is an extended class of seekBar which makes it custom element

Comment: If you don't want to have any code in the Activity this means that the View must maintain itself. Meaning that all your logic NEEDS to be inside the custom class. One view contains n of your custom Seekbars and then add that One view to your layout file.

Comment: Ok, I think I will go with the OnSeekBarChangeListener in the main activity

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to implement OnSeekBarChangeListener directly on your extended class:

```
public class SeekBarPlus extends SeekBar implements OnSeekBarChangeListener{

public SeekBarPlus(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    }

    public SeekBarPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    }

    public SeekBarPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    }

    ....
}
```

Otherwise none of the on* methods will get called. **Note:** this really should be a [composite widget](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound) and you shouldn't need to be passing in the TextView.

You also need to do what Sergio suggested and not use the `int` value directly: `numberOfDrills.setText("" + progress);`

Comment: Strange eclipse gives me the option to import OnSeekBarChangeListener, but it is not imported. Maybe I should add it manually?

Comment: it is asking to add android.widget.SeekBar,  but it already there.

Comment: Still no impact on the TextView fields. I will add a screen shot to the question, maybe it will help

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're sending an *int* to `setText()`, so it doesn't work because it expects a `String`. Change the line to:

```
numberOfDrills.setText("" + progress);
```

Or:

```
numberOfDrills.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
```

You may want to change this 4 lines too in your MainActivity, you are setting 4 TextViews to the same seekbar:

```
/*addSeekBar.setTextView(numberOfAddDrills);
addSeekBar.setTextView(numberOfSubDrills);
addSeekBar.setTextView(numberOfMulDrills);
addSeekBar.setTextView(numberOfDivDrills);*/

addSeekBar.setTextView(numberOfAddDrills);
subSeekBar.setTextView(numberOfSubDrills);
mulSeekBar.setTextView(numberOfMulDrills);
divSeekBar.setTextView(numberOfDivDrills);
```

Comment: Then the problem is other. This fixes `setText()`. I noticed another possible error in your code, see if that solves the problem. I edited my answer.

Comment: I didn't really understand what to change to what.

Comment: Thanks, but that too not solving this. I think it is something with the OnSeekBarChangeListener